# using HTTP headers for cache control in PHP

Tags: php, caching, http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control

How can I use HTTP headers to control when my cache should be updated?

At the moment I am using cURL to grab a live XML feed and then save it into an xml file.
The feed also sends HTTP headers notifying you of when it will be updated. The update can be anywhere between 30seconds and 3mins.

The header looks like this

```
Expires: Mon, 22 Nov 2011 10:01:22 GMT
```

and this is what I am currently using to check every 30seconds

```
if (file_exists($filename) && (filemtime($filename) > time() - 30)) {
```

I would prefer it to only update based on what the HTTP headers say.

How would I go about doing so?

Also is there a better way of caching this XML feed rather than saving it to a XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you will have to parse the date given in the headers:

```
$header = "Expires: Mon, 22 Nov 2011 10:01:22 GMT";
preg_match(
    "/Expires: [A-Za-z]+, ([0-9]{1,2}) ([A-Za-z]+) ([0-9]{4}) ([0-9:]+) ([A-Z]{3})/", 
    $header,
    $matches
);
$months = array(
    "Jan" => "01",
    "Feb" => "02", 
    "Mar" => "03",
    "Apr" => "04",
    "May" => "05",
    "Jun" => "06",
    "Jul" => "07",
    "Aug" => "08",
    "Sep" => "09",
    "Oct" => "10",
    "Nov" => "11",
    "Dec" => "12"
);
$day = $matches[1];
$month = $months[$matches[2]];
$year = $matches[3];
$time = $matches[4];
$zone = $matches[5];

$date = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day $time", new DateTimeZone($zone));
```

then you can check this against the actual time and only execute the update if the $date from the last update is reached

```
$now = new DateTime();
if($now > $date);
```

you should save the $date in a file or DB after you downloaded the XML and parsed the date.
next time you execute the script just check the saved date against the new DateTime() to see if you already have to update it, if not you can load the saved XML from the file.

saving the XML as file is good, you might save it to a Database, but I would not set up a DB only for saving one XML-Structure. If you want to keep a history of old XMLs the DB makes sense again.

Comment: note that this will already use the timezone provided properly.

Comment: okay, but how do I grab just the Expires: Mon, 22 Nov 2011 10:01:22 GMT and not all of the headers?

Comment: just put in the complete header, the regular expression should just match the line with the expires stuff...

Comment: Only just got time to test it and I am getting a fatal error. atal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Los_Angeles' for 'PST/-8.0/no DST' instead'

Comment: you can set the `$now = new DateTime("now",new DateTimeZone("GMT"));` and replace GMT with your local timezone like `Europe/Berlin` for Germany or `UTC` or something else...

Answer (score 0):

The `Expires` header tells you the time when the document will expire - i.e. "don't check until this date". Note that it specifies the timezone (GMT), so this may not be your local time.

Comment: from http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt, it's always supposed to be GMT+0, so it can easily be adjusted to the server timezone

Comment: @Esailija: Good point - with emphasis on "is supposed to"; 99% of servers will follow the RFC; some just won't. As for the GMT+0, that is not much of an issue e.g. for someone in GMT-5, as the discrepancy is large enough to be obvious, but as someone in GMT+1, not realizing the offset has bitten me at least once.